# OpenXml can't open docx file after vertically merged cells,

Tags: openxml-sdk

```
string path = @"D:\newdoc.docx" ;

using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(path, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)) 
{
    MainDocumentPart mainpart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainpart.Document = new Document();
    Body body = mainpart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());

    Table t = new Table();
    TableProperties tpr = new TableProperties(new TableWidth(){Width="0",Type=TableWidthUnitValues.Auto},new TableLook(){Val="04A0"});
    t.Append(tpr);
    TableGrid tg = new TableGrid(new GridColumn() { Width = "4261" }, new GridColumn() { Width = "4261" });
    t.Append(tg);

    TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
    TableCell r1tc1 = new TableCell();
    TableCell r1tc2 = new TableCell();
    tr1.Append(r1tc1);
    tr1.Append(r1tc2);

    TableRow tr2 = new TableRow();
    TableCell r2tc1 = new TableCell();
    TableCell r2tc2 = new TableCell();
    tr2.Append(r2tc1);
    tr2.Append(r2tc2);

    TableRow tr3 = new TableRow();
    TableCell r3tc1 = new TableCell();                   
    TableCellProperties r3tc1prp = new TableCellProperties();
     VerticalMerge vm = new VerticalMerge() { Val = MergedCellValues.Restart };
    r3tc1prp.Append(vm);              
    r3tc1.Append(r3tc1prp);

    TableCell r3tc2 = new TableCell(new TableCellProperties());
    tr3.Append(r3tc1);
    tr3.Append(r3tc2);

    TableRow tr4 = new TableRow();
    TableCell r4tc1 = new TableCell();
    r4tc1.TableCellProperties = new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth() { Width = "4261", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa });
    r4tc1.TableCellProperties.VerticalMerge = new VerticalMerge();


    TableCell r4tc2 = new TableCell();
    tr4.Append(r4tc1);
    tr4.Append(r4tc2);

    t.Append(tr1);
    t.Append(tr2);
    t.Append(tr3);
    t.Append(tr4);

    body.Append(t);
}
```

after create and saved the document, I can't open it with Word2007

> Error:`<p>` element must before element `</tc>`

I can't find `<p>` element in document.xml

troubled me for several days ,anyone can help  thxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can't find the `<p>` element in your document is actually the problem. The schema expects a `Paragraph` element in every `TableCell`; without the `Paragraph` the document is invalid. This leads to the rather cryptic error that you must have a `<p>` (open paragraph element) before a `</tc>` (close table cell element).

Adding a `Paragraph` to each `TableCell` you create will solve your problem. The easiest way to do that is to pass a `new Paragraph` to each `TableCell` constructor:

```
string path = @"D:\newdoc.docx";

using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(path, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainpart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainpart.Document = new Document();
    Body body = mainpart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());

    Table t = new Table();
    TableProperties tpr = new TableProperties(new TableWidth() { Width = "0", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Auto }, new TableLook() { Val = "04A0" });
    t.Append(tpr);
    TableGrid tg = new TableGrid(new GridColumn() { Width = "4261" }, new GridColumn() { Width = "4261" });
    t.Append(tg);

    TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
    TableCell r1tc1 = new TableCell(new Paragraph());
    TableCell r1tc2 = new TableCell(new Paragraph());
    tr1.Append(r1tc1);
    tr1.Append(r1tc2);

    TableRow tr2 = new TableRow();
    TableCell r2tc1 = new TableCell(new Paragraph());
    TableCell r2tc2 = new TableCell(new Paragraph());
    tr2.Append(r2tc1);
    tr2.Append(r2tc2);

    TableRow tr3 = new TableRow();
    TableCell r3tc1 = new TableCell(new Paragraph());
    TableCellProperties r3tc1prp = new TableCellProperties();
    VerticalMerge vm = new VerticalMerge() { Val = MergedCellValues.Restart };
    r3tc1prp.Append(vm);
    r3tc1.Append(r3tc1prp);

    TableCell r3tc2 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(), new TableCellProperties());
    tr3.Append(r3tc1);
    tr3.Append(r3tc2);

    TableRow tr4 = new TableRow();
    TableCell r4tc1 = new TableCell(new Paragraph());
    r4tc1.TableCellProperties = new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth() { Width = "4261", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa });
    r4tc1.TableCellProperties.VerticalMerge = new VerticalMerge();


    TableCell r4tc2 = new TableCell(new Paragraph());
    tr4.Append(r4tc1);
    tr4.Append(r4tc2);

    t.Append(tr1);
    t.Append(tr2);
    t.Append(tr3);
    t.Append(tr4);

    body.Append(t);
}
```